# Cannot make VueMapbox 100% of parent

Tags: vue.js, mapbox-gl

I am using a VueMapbox with markers and trying to display it in a parent container. I added this CSS because without this the map has 0 height and width:

```
.mapboxgl-map {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

I want the width to be 100% of the parent, so I added this which DOES work:

```
.mapboxgl-canvas {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

HOWEVER, when you drag the map or zoom in, the markers move around as if the map is the default size. I've tried messing around with the CSS and I haven't had any success.

I've also tried calling `map.resize()` after the map gets loaded. The function gets called but doesn't do anything and once you zoom in to the map, the background disappears. Here is my component:

```
<template>

  <MglMap :accessToken="accessToken" :mapStyle="mapStyle"
        :center="coordinates" 
        @load="onMapLoaded"
  >
    
    <MglMarker v-for="team in teams"
        :key="team.id"
        :coordinates="[team.lng, team.lat]"
    >
    </MglMarker>
      
  </MglMap>

</template>

<script>
import Mapbox from "mapbox-gl";
import { MglMap, MglGeojsonLayer, MglMarker, MglPopup } from "vue-mapbox";

export default {
  components: {
    MglMap,
    MglGeojsonLayer,
    MglMarker,
    MglPopup
  },
  mixins: [teamHelper],
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken: ...,
      mapStyle: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      
      coordinates: [-50.549668, 39.014],
      map: null,
      mapbox: null
    }
  },
  
  props: {
    teams: []
  },

  created() {
    this.mapbox = Mapbox
  },
  
  methods: {
    
    onMapLoaded(event) {
      this.map = event.map;
      this.map.resize();    // does not work
    },

  }
};
</script>
```

Once you resize the window it works as expected, so if there were a way to trigger that properly, then I feel like it should work. I've also read all of the similar questions on this I could find, and none helped, AND I read the documentation which does not mention anything about this.

I'm using Vue `^2.5.17` and vue-mapbox `^0.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

Alright well I found a somewhat hacky workaround. You just have to render the map component inside an IFrame, set the size of the IFrame to 100% of the parent and you're good to go.

If you need to pass data from the parent component to the child, you can do something like this: http://blog.pixelastic.com/2017/09/12/sending-data-to-an-iframe-with-vue-js/

If you have a better solution or know why the resizing wasn't working then please respond.